# sporadic error renaming a label with Gmail REST API -- known issue? workarounds?

Tags: gmail-api

We run a service that synchronizes with Gmail using the REST API. Since last Wednesday, some of our (unchanged) Gmail tests have begun sporadically failing. The cause *appears* to be on the Gmail REST API side.

One failing test involves creating a label, creating a message, tagging a message with the label, and then renaming the label. When the tests fail, the `POST` request to change the label name returns a **404** error. A `GET` on that label or on the label list, either before or after the first **404**, will successfully return the label in question. Retrying the `POST` keeps resulting in a **404** for at least 30 seconds, even with a 5-second gap between retries. Adding a 15-second delay before trying the `POST` doesn’t help.

Is this a known issue? If so, are there any known workarounds? What can we provide to help diagnose and fix this? We’re using the Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.22.0 client library.

Here's the request/response from a successful POST:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels/Label_4311
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: <Not Logged>
User-Agent: pexlabs Google-API-Java-Client Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.22.0 (gzip)
x-http-method-override: PATCH
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 38

{"name":"mystery"}


HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34,33,32"
Server: GSE
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
ETag: "SJIjOPuAzi7meWvLIr4rJgaI0K4/vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8"
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Origin
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Tue, 20 Sep 2016 15:30:51 GMT
```

Here's the request/response from a failed POST:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels/Label_4317
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: <Not Logged>
User-Agent: pexlabs Google-API-Java-Client Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.22.0 (gzip)
x-http-method-override: PATCH
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 38

{"name":"mystery"}


HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34,33,32"
Server: ESF
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 1596
Date: Tue, 20 Sep 2016 15:44:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/gmail/v1/users/me/labels/Label_4317</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Looking at a few runs, the `Server` response header value differs between successes and failures (though that may be by design).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very peculiar error. Patching of labels seem to be broken. I also get `Error 404 (Not Found)!!1`. What on earth?!

In the mean time your could just get the label data, and then update the fields that can be changed, but just changing the name to your liking:

**Request 1**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels/Label_203?access_token={access_token}
```

**Response 1**

```
{
 "id": "Label_203",
 "name": "test1234",
 "messageListVisibility": "show",
 "labelListVisibility": "labelShow",
 "type": "user",
 "messagesTotal": 0,
 "messagesUnread": 0,
 "threadsTotal": 0,
 "threadsUnread": 0
}
```

**Request 2**

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels/Label_203?access_token={access_token}

{
 "id": "Label_203",
 "labelListVisibility": "labelShow",
 "messageListVisibility": "show",
 "name": "test12345"
}
```

**Response 2**

```
{
 "id": "Label_203",
 "name": "test12345",
 "messageListVisibility": "show",
 "labelListVisibility": "labelShow"
}
```

### Update

The API Explorer does not work for some odd reason. However, if you change from `POST` to `PATCH` in your request, it will work:

**Request**

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels/Label_203?access_token={access_token}

{
  "name": "wow123"
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "id": "Label_203",
  "name": "wow123",
  "messageListVisibility": "show",
  "labelListVisibility": "labelShow",
  "type": "user",
  "messagesTotal": 0,
  "messagesUnread": 0,
  "threadsTotal": 0,
  "threadsUnread": 0
}
```